# Set button onclick property through URL bar?

Tags: javascript, createelement

Entering the following code in the URL bar (in safari) creates the required script tag and button in order to run [Together.js](https://togetherjs.com/#tryitout-section):

```
javascript:{var s=document.createElement('script');
s.src='https://togetherjs.com/togetherjs-min.js';
document.head.appendChild(s);
var b=document.createElement('button');
b.onclick='function(){TogetherJS(this); return false;}';
b.innerHTML='Start TogetherJS';document.body.appendChild(b);}
```

However, the `onclick` property of the button is not set. I have also tried setting the `onclick` property to a string value but have had no luck. How can I set the onclick property of the button?

PS. This is one of my first questions. Is there any thing I could improve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eval is actually not recommended but for your example this should work:

```
  b.onclick=eval('function clickHandler(){TogetherJS(this); return false;}');
```

or better use this:

```
  b.onclick=function(){TogetherJS(this); return false;};
```